# problem about cscope index hpp file

Tags: c++, cscope

i have template class A, the definition is in a.hpp

a.h

```
template <...>
A
{
void Test();
};
#include a.hpp
```

if let

```
cscope -bq a.h
```

then cscope can find Test declaration, but cannot find definition.

if let

```
cscope -bq a.h a.hpp
```

then cscope even cannot find Test declaration.
any advice?
thank you.

Comment: The syntax of the '`#include`' line is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of cscope on which platform?

With the code as shown:

#### a.h

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED
template <class T> A
{
    void Test(T a);
};
#include "a.hpp"
#endif /* A_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### a.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP_INCLUDED
#define A_HPP_INCLUDED
template <class T> A::Test(T a) { return !!a; }
#endif /* A_HPP_INCLUDED */
```

and using cscope 15.7a compiled on MacOS X (running on 10.6.4, probably compiled on an earlier version), I did:

```
cscope -b -q a.*
cscope -d
```

and then searched for Test and see:

```
C symbol: Test

  File  Function Line
0 a.h   <global> 5 void Test(T a);
1 a.hpp Test     3 template <class T> A::Test(T a) { return !!a; }
```

A search for `A::Test` comes back with the error:

```
This is not a C symbol: A::Test
```

So, superficially, you need to upgrade to cscope 15.7a (or downgrade to it?).